# Performance testing on SQL Server view resulted in surprising results. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-view

Recently, we made some changes to some SQL Server views that had the potential to negatively affect performance. We decided to run some performance tests on these views to see how we had affected them.  The results were surprising.

The graph below shows the results of the performance tests that we ran.  Here is what the graph represents:

- The blue line is the view before any changes were made.
- The red line shows the view after the changes were made.
- The x-axis represents iterations in a loop.

  - Each iteration, **a thousand new records** are inserted (that the view will return).
  - Each iteration, we do several selects from the view we are testing and average the results.
- The y-axis represents the time it takes for the view to return the results
- The select statement that was performance tested had a where clause on it to only return 100 records each time. (there were 100 records inserted on each name during the test).

The results show us that we definitely did take a performance hit, but the thing that baffles us is that huge increase in performance once we hit around 40,000 records in the database.  We have ran this test on **several different servers** and get similar results every time.

I am wondering if anyone can give insight into why this is happening.  Why do we get a **huge performance gain** when we breach the 40,000 record level?  Has anyone seen anything like this before?  I have tried searching for some reason for this, but have come up empty handed.

We have tried tweaking the view, messing with indexes, rebuilding and reorganizing indexes, analyzing the execution plan, and various other things, but so far we have not found anything that would cause this.

[image: View Performance]

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: And the rough table structure, indexes and view query are? Best guess with no information, you're index-scanning a table when you shouldn't be and the DB finally works this out and does a full-scan.

Comment: The view is quite complex, and the same goes for the indexes and table structure as well. I am solely looking for ideas on where to look to diagnose this issue. I will look more into the index scans vs. table scans that you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the before and after actual execution plans. Run the query at an "input size" where you are surprised with the perf difference. The issue is likely to be cardinality misestimation.

Comment: Posting the execution plan would be much more helpful.

Comment: Due to the sheer size of the query plan, it is impractical to post here.  Several of your responses have helped point me in the right direction though.  As @usr pointed out, I believe it does have something to do with cardinality misestimation.

Comment: How did you carry out this testing? I'd like to be able to do something very similar for a view change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should approach this just like any other performance investigation: use a sound methodology and measure. [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) will, again, be priceless a s a methodology to identify the bottlenecks. Once you identify and measure the relevant metrics then the answer can be given what's happening.

Right now you simply measured response time, w/o any actual data of how is the time spent. W/o a single actual data point presented (collected metrics, test specifications for others to attempt etc), *any* explanation could be ventured with equal chance of being right: client code, locking contention, file growth, log growth, index stats, query plan changes, human error, gremlins, moon rays and of course, my favorite: [fragmentation](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/31/the-bizzaro-guide-to-sql-server-performance/).

So either do the proper analysis and investigation and collect the relevant metrics, or post the exact test (repro scripts, methodology) so we can measure ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating statistics on the tables involved.

Perhaps your statistics were out of date and the plan that was used was the wrong plan for your number of rows.

Comment: +1 I believe SQL Server might auto update stats after X% of rows are modified, so every 1000 rows won't necessarily update the stats and they can get out of date. Also a random stab: 40K records is where the parallel cost is less than the estimated performance penalty of parallelising the query.